# How to select Particlur <li> tag in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I had taken input as array and stored it in the format of li now I have to select a particular li tag Like li tag of particular index.

```
function showItem(intArr){
    var newTask = "";
    intArr.forEach((element)=>{
        newTask+=`<li>${element}</li>`;
    })
    arrValue.innerHTML = newTask;
    console.log("item added");
}
```

```
var intArr = document.querySelector("input.arrayInput").value.split(" ").map(function (item) {
        return parseInt(item, 10);
    });
var idLow = intArr[low];
    // document.getElementById(idLow).style.backgroundColor = "#4ac7ee";
    // document.getElementById(idLow).style.color = "#ffffff";
```

Here I have to select li tag which is at an index low.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('lowIndexNo')[low]`?

Comment: Does your `<li>` tag have a class or id?

Comment: No but I can add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give an ID to the parent `ul`/`ol` tag, get it by ID and then get the child `<li>` tags using `children`:

```js
var low = 0;
var element = document.getElementById("list").children[low];
document.write(element);
document.write(element.innerText);
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```